# process responses from /dev/tcp in bash

Tags: bash, tcp

I connect to a server by /dev/tcp to receive incoming messages. To hold the connection open I must send an request every 10 seconds. This works fine with the script below. My problem is: How can I process the incoming messages in a function within the script?

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/192.168.24.23/1234

while true
    do
        cat <&3 &

        while true
            do
                echo -en "hold-connection-request" >&3
                sleep 10
            done
    done
```

Instead of cat I want to process the responses string in a function like processResponse(). The messages are strings with more than one line.

```
processResponse() {
    RESPONSE=$1
    # do something with this string
}
```

Comment: this gives me a lot of empty lines in the $1

Comment: Oops - I deleted the wrong comment. Mea Culpa.
Trying to come up with something actually useful instead of offhand ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly just repeating chepner above, but using a read to grab and pass the string. Limited opportunity to test here, let me know if that doesn't work.

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/192.168.24.23/1234

processResponse() {
  RESPONSE=$1 # blanks around = removed
  # do something with this string
}

while sleep 10
do echo -en "hold-connection-request"
done >&3 &
anchor=$!

while read response
do processResponse $response
done <&3

ps -p $anchor >/dev/null && kill $anchor || echo No process $anchor to kill
```

Comment: thx for help! By the way within the processResponse I had to remove the blanks bevor and after the =.

Comment: OOPS! I just copy/pasted the template from yours, sorry. Will dit both so anyone grabbing code from this later doesn't hit that too.

Comment: I just noticed that read stops after the first blank character in the message. The message is in xml, like <firsttag><secondtag>message with blanks</secondtag></firsttag>. Can I solve it perhaps by integrate the xml-tag in the while-loop?

Comment: Post an update to the OP with the code you are using and a description of the behavior - or it might be worth a new question. If you post it as a new question, link it to me here. I'll try to take a look.

Comment: I continued this problem in a new question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47636710/read-full-message-in-a-while-loop-in-bash

Comment: As mentioned there - put quotes around "$response" when sending to the func as I should have done in my example, check your syntax at places like [this](https://explainshell.com) and/or [this](https://shellcheck.net), and assume you're going to have to handle everything manually if you aren't using an XML-aware tool.

Answer (score 0):

Run the watchdog loop in the background, not your processor.

```
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/192.168.24.23/1234
while true; do
    printf 'hold-connection-request' >&3
    sleep 10; wait  # Make it interruptible
done &
watchdog=$!

while true; do
    # process requests
done <&3

kill "$watchdog"  # If you need to
```

Comment: That's fine so far. But how I have to call processResponse in the second while loop with the <&3 as parameter? As a result I only get empty arguments within the function processResponse()

Comment: Complementary: My plan is to post the incoming responses with curl to a webserver by a POST request. Perhaps there is a easier way.