# Read full message in a while loop in bash

Tags: xml, bash, tcp, while-loop

I connect to a server by /dev/tcp to receive incoming xml messages. The script below is running well, but if there is an blank character in the xml message, the message is abrupt. But I need the to read full message. Can I solve this by integrate the closing xml-tag in the while-loop?

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/192.168.24.23/1234

processResponse() {
  RESPONSE=$1 
  if [[${RESPONSE:0:10} == "<firsttag>" ]]; then
    curl -X POST --data "postdata=$RESPONSE" http://localhost/index.php
  fi 
}

while read response
    do processResponse $response
done <&3
```

The xml-message will be like:

```
<firsttag>
   <secondtag>message with blanks inside</secondtag>
</firsttag>
```

Comment: The if statement has two syntax errors.

Comment: `read` is line-oriented, which isn't suitable for consuming something like XML in which newlines are effectively arbitrary whitespace. That said, your immediate issue is probably the failure to quote `$response`: `processRespones "$response"`.

Comment: You should really be using a language with a proper XML parser (and an HTTP library) instead of `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

As chepner said, your approach isn't really suitable, but if you must forgo an XML parser, you can solve this for cases like the shown one. Rather than scripting a `while` loop, I'd use `awk` to read and assemble the message lines.

```
awk '/<firsttag>/   { RESPONSE = "" }
     /<firsttag>/,/<\/firsttag>/    { RESPONSE = RESPONSE$0 }
     /<\/firsttag>/ { system("curl -X POST --data \"postdata="RESPONSE"\" http://localhost/index.php") }
    ' <&3
```